# iPhone Navigation Controller Bar with no title

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to know how to hide the title of a `UINavigationBar`.

I have a root view controller where I'd like to have a navigation bar but without any title.

I used `[self setTitle:@""];` but in this case after a segue to the next view controller I cannot go back.

If I donnot set the in the storyboard and donnot set anything by code everything works perfectly except on the next view controller I have a very ugly "Back" button which I would like to set title to "Home".

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: tried setting `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`?

Comment: unfortunately I use the inferred designs from the storyboard, making the view controller `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` or `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` equal to `nil`

Comment: what 'makes' it nil? Your code?

Comment: I donnot declare a navigation controller in my views, I use the UINavigationController from my storyboard. I donnot have any code for it in my source files

Comment: I still don't see why can't you just set `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`.

Comment: I could but won't I have to design the button to look like what it should ? with the arrow on the right, the callback, etc

Comment: nice, could you post it as an answer so I can accept it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
```

property to an UIBarButtonItem of your choice - UIKit will make it nice for you automagically.